# Subsonic 2.2 & Sqlite

Tags: .net, sqlite, subsonic, system.data.sqlite, subsonic2.2

I've tried to use Subsonic 2.2 & System.Data.Sqlite.Dll latest version (1.65.0),
in my project.

and recevied an error message, which gave me the idea subsonic got a problem with the sqilte provider.

I've switched to it's previous version, 1.60.0 and it seems like the problem was solved.

any info regarding this issue? 
does subsonic 2.2 fits version 1.60.0 only? and if so, can it be updated to fit the latest
sqlite .net provider version?

Shahar Weinstein.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. To me it looked like SubSonic was built for the specific version 1.0.60.0 and therefore needs that version.

I guess if you need to use 1.0.65.0 for some reason you'd have to download the SubSonic 2.2 source and recompile it, changing the System.Data.SQLite reference.